# Getting percentages in legend from pie matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have created a pie chart using matplotlib below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = ['dogs','cats','birds','fish']
sizes = [34, 24,18,13]
pie = plt.pie(sizes,autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.legend( loc = 'right', labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Instead of having the percentages on the pie slices, is there a way to put these percentages within the legend so that the legend reads:

dogs, 34%

cats, 24%

birds, 18%

fish, 13%

I know I can just change the "labels" to read the above as the fastest and most elegant way, but what if you do not know "sizes" until after the code is ran?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume by the time you draw the legend, you should know `sizes`. Something like this would do it:

```py
# use a list comprehension to update the labels
labels = [f'{l}, {s:0.1f}%' for l, s in zip(labels, sizes)]
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 1), loc='upper left', labels=labels)
```

[image]

- Older string formatting style

```py
labels = ['%s, %1.1f %%' % (l, s) for l, s in zip(labels, sizes)]
```