# how to create PI chart in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

Hi Python Experts,

PI chart is not coming up nicely because of long column names & smaller slices. In this example, you can see that i have 6 buckets but in PI chart, only 5 slices are visible. Even text labeled with slices (top right) and on top are overlapping with each other. Table width is also not sufficient to fit column content. Could you please suggest what is the best way to deal with such situation ? I am new comer to python. I am using anaconda python 3.6.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import table

raw_data = {'FLAG' : ['AT-NBBO', 'BETTER-THAN-NBBO', 'ONE-SIDED-QUOTE', 'OUTSIDE-NBBO', 'OUTSIDE-NBBO-DUE-TO-OVERSIZED-BUT-NO-EXECUTION-WITHIN-NBBO', 'OUTSIDE-NBBO-DUE-TO-OVERSIZED-BUT-SOME-EXECUTION_WITHIN_NBBO'],
     'COUNT' : [10840, 8628, 84, 633, 153, 14]
   }
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['FLAG', 'COUNT'])

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
df.plot(kind='pie', y = 'COUNT', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
  startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=df['FLAG'], legend = True, 
fontsize=14)


# plot table
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
plt.axis('off')
tbl = table(ax2, df, loc='right')
tbl.auto_set_font_size(False)
tbl.set_fontsize(20)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Click Here to visualize the Chart]

Comment: As commented before on your previous (identical version of this) question: how would you like the plot to look like instead? Maybe you can use a sketch drawn by hand or paint program to make that clearer. Also, what exactly *is* `table`? Nobody can run your code if it is not complete and verifiable, so if you want a solution concerning the `table` you need to share the function that creates it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, did you try to run my code ? It’s a complete code and produces the output as shown above. I deleted my previous post because you had marked as duplicate and first as not complete hence created the new one. Table shows the contents of the data frame which is not fitting inside the table. This is clearly visible in my output. I am not sure what exactly are you looking here ? Are you a moderator of this forum?

Comment: Yes I even did try to run your code although it is already obvious by looking at it that `table` is not defined anywhere, so when running it, it will produce an error `NameError: name 'table' is not defined`. In order for this question to be answered one would need to know how you would like your plot to look like instead of how it looks now. I am not a moderator, but I often try to explain to people what is needed for their question to be answerable (from the number (5) next to my comment above, you see that 5 people agree with me on this one).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Thanks for your suggestion. I am not sure why you are getting the error. Probably your python version is different than mine. I am using Python3.6. I just added additional import in my above code. In my code, you can see that i have 6 buckets but in pi chart only 5 are visible. Out of that text label with 3 slices (top right) are overlapping with each other. In table also you can see that text is appearing outside of table width. Could you please help me to find the solution for my problem ?

Comment: Because you made this code runnable now (including all needed imports) I can now reproduce the image from the question. The missing "bucket" is indeed in the plot, but it is so small compared to the others that it is barely observable. So that leads again to the question how you would like your plot to look like instead? Same for the table; how would you like the long label fit into the table? Would you like to decrease the fontsize to make it fit or do you want a larger table?

Comment: Thank you for your time in understanding the situation. Regarding table, Yes, i would prefer a bigger table where first column should be wide enough to fit long label and second column width should be smaller to hold numeric values. Regarding PI chart, by making the chart bigger, is it possible to show smallest slice ? If not then could you please suggest how does data analytics team prefer to plot such data distribution ? My intent is to show data distribution and percentage in an visual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the table you may adjust the ratio of the two suplots and the subplot margins to make more space for the table. Then you may also change the table columns width ratio.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import table

raw_data = {'FLAG' : ['AT-NBBO', 'BETTER-THAN-NBBO', 'ONE-SIDED-QUOTE', 'OUTSIDE-NBBO', 'OUTSIDE-NBBO-DUE-TO-OVERSIZED-BUT-NO-EXECUTION-WITHIN-NBBO', 'OUTSIDE-NBBO-DUE-TO-OVERSIZED-BUT-SOME-EXECUTION_WITHIN_NBBO'],
     'COUNT' : [10840, 8628, 84, 633, 153, 14]
   }
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['FLAG', 'COUNT'])


fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(16,6), 
      gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[1,2.]})
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.97, wspace=0.4)
ax1.set_aspect("equal")
df.plot(kind='pie', y = 'COUNT', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
  startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=df['FLAG'], legend = True, 
fontsize=14)

ax2.axis("off")
tbl = table(ax2, df, loc='center',colWidths=[0.9,0.10])
print tbl
tbl.auto_set_font_size(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Table looks perfect now. PI chart labels (top right) are overlapping with each other. Is there a way to fix by adjusting the height ? If not then can i get rid of label and show the percentage in the legend ?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076203/getting-percentages-in-legend-from-pie-matplotlib-pie-chart

Comment: Thanks. By following that suggestion, i tried something like below but it doesn't gives me correct percentage in legends as it appears over chart. I don't want to show label and percentage on chart because text is overlapping due to long string and small slices.               
                                                                                          
     df.plot(kind='pie', y = 'COUNT', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
  startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=['%s, %1.1f %%' % (l, s) for l, s in zip(df['FLAG'],df['COUNT'])], legend = True, 
fontsize=20)