# resizing pie chart slices in matplotlib so that percentages are visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have this code that gets the levenshtein distance between a correct word and it's mispelling

```
def show_pie_of_levenshtein(df: pandas.DataFrame, title: str):
    counts_dict = dict()

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        noised = str(row['Noised'])
        correct = str(row['Correct'])

        distance = levenshtein(noised, correct)

        if distance in counts_dict.keys():
            counts_dict[distance] += 1
        else:
            counts_dict[distance] = 1

    distances = counts_dict.keys()
    counts = counts_dict.values()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(len(counts), 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

    def func(pct, allvals):
        return "{:.1f}%".format(pct)

    wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(counts, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, counts),
                                      textprops=dict(color="w"))

    ax.legend(wedges, distances,
              title="Distance",
              loc="center left",
              bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))

    plt.setp(autotexts, size=8, weight="bold")

    ax.set_title(title)

    plt.show()
```

But for some really low percentages the the slices and percentages prints are way too small to see, because they overlap with the other really small percentages.
[image]

How can I fix this so that the percentages are visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pctdistance` and `labeldistance` attributes in `ax.pie`.

If this does not work well, another option is to add a legend including the percentages instead of using text on the pie chart itself. Something like what I link here may work (I haven't tested it myself): [Getting percentages in legend from pie matplotlib pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076203/getting-percentages-in-legend-from-pie-matplotlib-pie-chart)

You would have an array of `labels` and an array of `percentages`.

Comment: I played around with setting them to different values to fix this and they didn't seem to separate them well enough to be readible.

Comment: sorry I'm new to matplotlib, how would I create a legend for that? the pie chart automatically converts to percentages for you.