# How to create a pie-chart from pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

I have a dataframe, with `Count` arranged in decending order, that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Topic': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'],
                   'Count': [80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20]})
```

But with more than 50 rows.

I would like to create a pie chart for the top 10 topics and rest of them to be summed up and represent its percentange as label "`Others`" in the pie chart. Is it possible to exclude the pie labels against each pie, and mention them seperately in a legend?

Thanking in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Topic` by `Other` if no top `N` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then aggregate `sum` with [`Series.plot.pie`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.pie.html):

```
N = 10
df['Topic'] = df['Topic'].where(df['Count'].isin(df['Count'].nlargest(N)), 'Other')

s = df.groupby('Topic')['Count'].sum()

pie = df.plot.pie(y='Count', legend=False)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076433/2901002
labels = [f'{l}, {s:0.1f}%' for l, s in zip(s.index, s / s.sum())]
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 1), loc='upper left', labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to craft a new dataframe. Assuming your counts are sorted in descending order (if not, use `df.sort_values(by='Count', inplace=True)`):

```
TOP = 10
df2 = df.iloc[:TOP]
df2 = df2.append({'Topic': 'Other', 'Count': df['Count'].iloc[TOP:].sum()},
                 ignore_index=True)

df2.set_index('Topic').plot.pie(y='Count', legend=False)
```

Example (N=10, N=5):

[image: pie chart]
[image: pie chart N=5]

Percentages in the legend:

```
N = 5
df2 = df.iloc[:N]
df2 = df2.append({'Topic': 'Other', 'Count': df['Count'].iloc[N:].sum()}, ignore_index=True)

df2.set_index('Topic').plot.pie(y='Count', legend=False)
leg = plt.legend(labels=df2['Count'])
```

output:

[image: plot with legend]

Comment: Thank you. I want to set ```legend = True``` and display the percentage of each pie against its legend, excluding the labels which are assigned right now. Can you please guide me how to do the latter?

Comment: Sure, see update

Comment: Great, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Topic': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'],
                   'Count': [80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20]})
df.index = df.Topic
plot = df.plot.pie(y='Count', figsize=(5, 5))
plt.show()
```

Use documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html

Comment: Dear @dinesh, thank you for the response. However, can you please suggest me how can I display top 10 or top 5 topics only? And adding the count for the rest of them and displaying it as "Others/Other Topics"?